# JQ object selection without endless filter chains

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm having difficulty using `jq (1.5)` to parse deeply nested JSON structures, and I feel like I'm using it wrong.  Take this example JSON input:

```
{
 "a":[],
 "b":[
  {"x":"bar", "s":"FX", "f":["blorg","blarg","blurb"], "v":true},
  {"x":"bar", "s":"EX", "f":["blorg","blarg","bloob"], "v":false},
  {"x":"bar", "s":"XT", "f":["blorg","blart","bloop"], "v":true},
  {"x":"bar", "s":"IJ", "f":["blorg","bleep","glarp"], "v":true},
  {"x":"foo", "s":"IX", "f":["porg","parg","pork","peep"], "v":true},
  {"x":"baz", "s":"AB", "f":["zing","zang","zoop"], "v":false}
  ],
 "c":[]
}
```

- To extract objects in list `b` where `x` is "bar" is straightforward:

  `jq '.["b"][] | select(.x == "bar")' < file.json`
- To restrict further to an object with a particular value of `s` is also simple:

  `jq '.["b"][] | select(.x == "bar" and .s == "FX")' < file.json`

If I want to apply a regular expression test, though, or any other test that requires a string input (bearing in mind that I still need object outputs), I think I have no choice but to chain filters.  For example ...

- To restrict to objects where `s` ends in "X", unfortunately the following isn't a thing in `jq`:

  `jq '.["b"][] | select(.x == "bar" and .s.endswith("X"))' < file.json`

  Instead I think I have to do this:

  `jq '.["b"][] | select(.x == "bar") | select(.s | endswith("X"))' < file.json`
- Similarly with `s` contains "X":

  `jq '.["b"][] | select(.x == "bar") | select(.s | test("X"))' < file.json`

Which is fine if I'm always doing boolean `AND`s, but what if I want to do an `OR`?  For example, what is the `jq` program to get objects where `x` is "bar" `OR` `s` ends in "X"?  Does `jq` have an `|OR|` filter?

```
jq '.["b"][] | select(.x == "bar") |OR| select(.s | endswith("X"))' < file.json
```

Or am I just doing it wrong?  Am I attempting to reinvent some standard `jq` algorithm for selecting objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforwardly (specify all of your conditions within `select` function):

```
jq -c '.b[] | select(.x == "bar" or (.s | endswith("X")))' file.json
```

The output:

```
{"x":"bar","s":"FX","f":["blorg","blarg","blurb"],"v":true}
{"x":"bar","s":"EX","f":["blorg","blarg","bloob"],"v":false}
{"x":"bar","s":"XT","f":["blorg","blart","bloop"],"v":true}
{"x":"bar","s":"IJ","f":["blorg","bleep","glarp"],"v":true}
{"x":"foo","s":"IX","f":["porg","parg","pork","peep"],"v":true}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Does the sub-parenthetical have a special meaning in `jq` or is it just to separate the second test from the first?

Comment: @dg99m, welcome, we specify inner parentheses here to separate an expression from the main pipe